# Pause GSAP animation after 2nd react component rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, gsap

Trying to pause or remove GSAP animation within the `else` part of this conditional..

Container code -

```
     renderNews = () => {
  /**
   * Renders news snippets, no filtering at this time
   */
    let max = 2
    let count = 0
    let posts = this.props.posts.map((article) => {
      count++
      console.log('count' + count)
      console.log('renderNews article => ', article)
      if (count <= max) {
        return (
          <Grid md={0.5} sm={1} key={article.id} >
            <SnippetNewsEvents
              image={article.featured_media}
              event={false}
              title={article.title.rendered}
              date={moment(article.date_gmt).format('Do MMMM YYYY')}
              excerpt={article.excerpt.rendered}
              buttonText='Read More'
              link={'/posts/' + article.slug}
            />
          </Grid>
        )
      } else {
        return ( // or whatever the right grid thing is
          <Grid md={1 / 3} sm={1 / 2} xs={1} key={article.id} >
            <SnippetNewsEvents
              //innerRef={null}
              image={article.featured_media}
              title={article.title.rendered}
              date={moment(article.date_gmt).format('Do MMMM YYYY')}
              //  excerpt={article.excerpt.rendered}
              buttonText='Read More'
              link={'/posts/' + article.slug}
            />
          </Grid>
      )
      }
    })
    return posts
  }
```

Component Code -

```
export default class SnippetNewsEvents extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      image: null
    }
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getImage(this.props.image)
    this.contentTween = new TimelineMax().add([
      TweenMax.fromTo(this.wrapper, 1, {
        scale: '0.95'
      }, {
        scale: '1'
      })])

    this.scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: this.wrapper, triggerHook: 0.8, duration: window.innerHeight/2})
                  .setTween(this.contentTween)
                  .addIndicators({name: 'snippets'})
                  .addTo(scrollController)
  }
  getImage (image) {
    if (typeof image === 'string') {
      this.setState({image: image})
    } else if (typeof image === 'number' && image !== 0) {
      fetch('http://hkserverdev.weruinit.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/' + image)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({image: data.source_url})
      }).catch(error => {
        if (dev) console.error('Error:', error)
      })
    }
  }
  showImage (image) {
    if (this.state.image == null) {
      return null
    } else {
      return (
        <SnippetImage src={this.state.image} data-rjs='2' />
      )
    }
  }
  showLocation = () => {
    if (this.props.event) {
      return (
        <EventsDetailWrapper>
          <H3c title={this.props.title}>{this.props.title}</H3c>
          <EventsTimeLocation>
            <Combo>
              <Icon className='buttonIcon' src={require('../../images/time_icon.png')} data-rjs='2' />
              <Detail copy={this.props.date} news />
            </Combo>
            <Combo>
              <Icon className='buttonIcon' src={require('../../images/location_icon.png')} />
              <Detail copy={this.props.location} />
            </Combo>
          </EventsTimeLocation>
        </EventsDetailWrapper>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <NewsDetailWrapper>
          <Detail uppercase={this.props.event} copy={this.props.date} />
          <H3c>{this.props.title}</H3c>
          <Detail excerpt copy={this.props.excerpt} />
        </NewsDetailWrapper>
      )
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.scene = this.scene.destroy()
  }
  render (props) {
    if (dev) console.log('SnippetNewsEvents => ', this.props)
    return (
      <EventsItemWrapper innerRef={c => (this.wrapper = c)} className='snippet' small={this.props.compressed}>
        {this.showImage(this.props.image)}
        {this.showLocation(this.props.event)}
        <Button className='hvr-trim hvr-trim-alt' black snippet link={this.props.link} content='Read More'>{this.props.content}</Button>
      </EventsItemWrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm new to both react and GSAP and js :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you've defined `this.scene` in `SnippetNewsEvents`, you can use a `ref` to stop the animation.

You should turn `renderNews` into a `class` component and then use its lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps` to either stop or start the animation. Let's see how this might be implemented:

```
container component

...

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 nextProps.posts.map((article) => count++ ...));
 // condition is met, stop animation
 if (count > max) { this.snippetNewEventsRef.contentScene.pause(); return; }
}

render() {
  return (...<SnippetNewsEvents ref={(c) => this.snippetNewsEventsRef = c} .../>);
}
```

This is off the top of my head though, so test it first. It should work: in this case, `this.snippetNewsEventsRef` is an object that will have a key `contentTween`.

Edit: tested, working. See JSBin [here](https://jsbin.com/yefizoqewi/edit?html,js,console,output)